# Find max X value in 2 variables equation

Tags: javascript, java, math, mathematical-optimization

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptNkt.png

**1.12579<x<8.87821, z = (20000000 x)/(1999 x + 19980000)**

Hi! I have a such mathematic equation, how can I find max **Z**?

Any solution except brute force works for me.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily sound like a programming question but a math question.  (Some calculus might be appropriate.)

Answer (score 0):

Find the local extrema of `z(x)` by solving

```
z'(x) = 0
```

Either there is a maxima in the range for x or the maximum will be one of the borders of the range.

Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#First-derivative_test for the theory.